# Launchctl load -w generate Service cannot load in requested session

Tags: launchd, plist

I ran the following command:

```
launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchAgents/...plist
```

The plist file has the following values:

```
<key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>
        <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/dev/null</string>
        <key>StandardOutPath</key>
        <string>/dev/null</string>
        <key>LimitLoadToSessionType</key>
        <string>Aqua</string>
        <key>ProcessType</key>
        <string>Interactive</string>
```

When I run:

```
sudo launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Library/LaunchAgents/...plist`
```

I got

```
/Applications/...app/Contents/scripts/...plist: Service is disabled
```

And then I ran:

```
launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchAgents/...plist
```

with the error:

```
Service cannot load in requested session
```

Answer (score 0):

```
iMac-de-Imac:~ imac$ echo $(id -u)
501

iMac-de-Imac:~ imac$ sudo launchctl enable gui/$(idu)/com.piriform.ccleaner
Password:

iMac-de-Imac:~ imac$

iMac-de-Imac:~ imac$ sudo launchctl bootstrap gui/$(id -u) /Library/LaunchAgents/com.piriform.ccleaner.plist

Password:
/Applications/CCleaner.app/Contents/scripts/com.piriform.ccleaner.plist: Service is disabled

iMac-de-Imac:~ imac$
```

When I try to open the CCleaner program in the System.log, the following appears:

```
Jan  9 10:51:24 iMac-de-Imac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1
(com.piriform.ccleaner.1944[550]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
```